# Java ME with Eclipse in Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-7, java-me, java-6

I have installed JDK 1.6 (32-bit) and Eclipse (32-bit) in Windows 7 (64-bit). So now I very want to program J2ME projects (32-bit) in my system, how can I do that ?

Comment: did you mean how to write code for 64 bits ? kindly clear your question first.

Comment: No, i want to write 32-bit code (most widely).

Comment: Well I guess there is no difference in writing codes 32 bits or 64 bits. Try making one HelloWorld Program, it works for both 32 bit & 64 bits.

Comment: But when I search on internet, I see some problem when use Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2 with eclipse in OS 64-bit.

Comment: well try making one Hello World Program & see what errors you are getting. I am sure there wont be any change in writing codes.

Comment: thanks for your help. I will ask you later if I have the problem.

Comment: Sure this website is for knowledge sharing purpose only. everybody are welcome to ask the question. I believe it is also one way of learning. May be I will also learn from your Question. Good Luck John

Answer (score 0):

Besides JDK and Eclipse , you should at least install the following tools too :

- [Java ME SDK 3.0.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/sdk/index.html)  or [Java Wireless Toolkit for CLDC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-137162.html)

  The  Wireless Toolkit (WTK) for CLDC  has been integrated into Java ME SDK 3.0 and Oracle highly recommends to use Java ME SDK 3.0 over Java Wireless Toolkit for CLDC
- [EclipseME](http://eclipseme.org/docs/installation.html)  - Eclipse plug-in for J2ME development

You could refer to this [guide](http://code.google.com/p/j4me/wiki/Setup) to setup the Java ME eclipse  development environment .

Comment: Some midlet files can run with Wireless toolkit several times but after I have a problem: "Warning: Failed to initialize WMA message routing support
Warning: Failed to initialize Bluetooth (JSR 82) support", my midlets can't run anymore. Please help me!